Can "Go to Definition" go to a concrete class in VSCode / Python (Pylance) during debugging?
I define an attribute of type MyAbstractClass (abstract class), which takes a value of a concrete subclass MyConcreteClass. When I hit "Go to Definition" in VSCode at poke in self.item.poke(), it takes me to MyAbstractClass.poke(), which is expected.
However, at runtime in the debug mode, when container.item is bound to an instance of MyConcreteClass, the IDE could do better and take me to MyConcreteClass.poke(). Are there any easy ways to make this happen?
All I want is more convenience when editing and debugging my code.
One option is to replace item : MyAbstractClass with item : Union[MyAbstractClass, MyConcreteClass, MyConcreteClass2, ...], in which case "Go to Definition" will produce a pop up with all listed methods, which would allow me to jump through them. However, having to manually list all possible subclasses defeats modularity, also I have to check the object's concrete type myself. Is there a solution that automates this and takes advantage of Python dynamic resolution infrastructure?
Another option is to remove all type hints. Then "Go to Definition" at debug mode jumps directly to the concrete method implementation. This is at the cost of it not working at all, unless the debugger is running and container.item is bound.
Neither of the options is optimal. I want to have the best in both situations: jumping to the abstract method when editing offline and jumping to the concrete method when debugging.
from abc import ABC,  abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def poke(self):
        pass

class MyConcreteClass(MyAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def poke(self):
        print("Poked!")

class MyContainerClass():
    item : MyAbstractClass
    def __init__(self, item: MyAbstractClass):
        self.item = item

    def poke_item(self):
        self.item.poke()

item = MyConcreteClass()
container = MyContainerClass(item=item)
container.poke_item()



related-ish? https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/discussions/2642. anyhow, you might want to raise this with the debugpy people at https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/discussions. if you do, please add a link here to your discussion.
